# Sum Lists' value with corresponding index value in Python

Tags: python, list, sum

I used a big list to represent a lot of needed values, which is really complicated to me.

For example:

```
    [[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]],
     [[g,h,i],[j,k,l]],
     [[o,p,u],[r,s,t]]]
```

And I want to combine the three major indices and their corresponding value together. I don't mean to concatenate.

For example the result would be:

```
    [[(a+g+o),(b+h+p),(c+i+u)],[(d+j+r),(e+k+s),(f+l+t)]]
```

Can someone help me how to accomplish this result? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. Since you said adding, I am assuming a, b, c, etc are all integers.

```
>> a = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
... [[7,8, 9],[10, 11, 12]],
... [[16, 17, 18],[13, 14, 15]]]

>>> temp_list = list(zip(*b) for b in zip(*a))
>>> result = [[sum(list(a)) for a in b] for b in temp_list]
>>> result
[[24, 27, 30], [27, 30, 33]]
```

An intimidating one-liner would be:

```
[[sum(list(a)) for a in b] for b in list(zip(*b) for b in zip(*a))]
```

Let's step through the code line by line.

1. `zip(*a)` will give you:

   ```
   >>> zip(*a)
   [([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [16, 17, 18]), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15])]
   ```

   It combined the first inner most lists of the sublists.
2. We need to do another `zip` on this. 
   `list(zip(*b) for b in zip(*a))` will give us:

   ```
   [[(1, 7, 16), (2, 8, 17), (3, 9, 18)], [(4, 10, 13), (5, 11, 14), (6, 12, 15)]]
   ```
3. Now we just need to sum these and create a list of lists. So we do:

   ```
   [[sum(list(a)) for a in b] for b in temp_list]
   ```

If the lists are going to be large, I would suggest using `itertools`' version of `zip` called [`izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). But `izip()` returns a generator and not a list. So, you would need to convert it to lists.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of thing really calls for `numpy`:

```
>>> a = [[[ 1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6]],
        [ [ 7, 8, 9], [10,11,12]],
        [ [13,14,15], [16,17,18]]]
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.array(a).sum(axis=0)
array([[21, 24, 27],
       [30, 33, 36]])
```

The `array` function converts the data to a numpy array.  Such arrays can be manipulated quite powerfully.  In your case, you want to sum along the first (that is, zeroth) axis.  This is done by invoking `sum(axis=0)`.