Sum of corresponding values from different arrays of the same size with Python
I'm rather new to Python so it's quite possible that my question has already been asked on the net but when I find things that seem relevant, I don't always know how to use them in my code (especially if it's a function definition), so I apologise if there's any redundancy.
I work with daily temperature data from the Copernicus website (https://marine.copernicus.eu/).
As the netCDF files are too large if I want the data for every day of every month for several years, what I'm trying to do is access the data without downloading it so that I can work with it.
The data is in the form of an array for 1 day of a month of a year.
I want to sum the values of all the arrays for each day of a month in a year.
To make things clearer, here's an example:
Simplified arrays :
array1([1,4,3,9]
       [7,5,2,3])

array2([3,8,6,1]
       [6,4,7,2])

#... etc until day 28,29,30 or 31

The result I want :
array1 + array 2 => ([1+3,4+8,3+6,9+1]
                     [7+6,5+4,2+7,3+2])


array1 + array 2 => ([4,12,9,10]
                     [13,9,9,5])

I first tried to do it without loop with the data for 2 days and it works.
My code :
import os
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc
import copernicusmarine

# Access the data
DS = copernicusmarine.open_dataset(dataset_id="cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083deg_P1D-m")

# Get only thetao (temperature) variable for 1 day
subset = DS[['thetao']].sel(time = slice("2014-01-01", "2014-01-01"))

# Obtain only data of a certain depth
target_depth = 0         #surface
subset_T = subset.thetao.isel(depth=target_depth)

# To view my data in array
thetao_depth0 = subset_T.data
thetao_depth0

# Same thing for next day of the same month and year
subset2 = DS[['thetao']].sel(time = slice("2014-01-02", "2014-01-02"))

subset_T2 = subset2.thetao.isel(depth=target_depth)

thetao_depth0_2 = subset_T2.data
thetao_depth0_2

# The sum of my arrays
days_sum = thetao_depth0 + thetao_depth0_2
days_sum

My thetao_depth0 arrays look like this :
For 01/01/2014 :
array([[[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        ...,
        [-1.70870081, -1.70870081, -1.70870081, ..., -1.70870081,
         -1.70870081, -1.70870081],
        [-1.71016569, -1.71016569, -1.71016569, ..., -1.71016569,
         -1.71016569, -1.71016569],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan]]])

For 02/01/2014 :
array([[[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        ...,
        [-1.70870081, -1.70870081, -1.70870081, ..., -1.70870081,
         -1.70870081, -1.70870081],
        [-1.71016569, -1.71016569, -1.71016569, ..., -1.71016569,
         -1.71016569, -1.71016569],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan]]])

And I get days_sum :
array([[[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        ...,
        [-3.41740161, -3.41740161, -3.41740161, ..., -3.41740161,
         -3.41740161, -3.41740161],
        [-3.42033139, -3.42033139, -3.42033139, ..., -3.42033139,
         -3.42033139, -3.42033139],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan]]])

Now here's where it gets complicated.
I'd like to create a loop that does the same thing with all the arrays for every day of a month in a year (from 01/01/2014 to 31/01/2014 for example).
So far I've done this :
day = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']
month = ['01']
year = ['2014']

DS = copernicusmarine.open_dataset(dataset_id="cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083deg_P1D-m")

for y in year:
    for m in month:
        for d in day:
            start_date="%s"%y+"-%s"%m+"-%s"%d
            end_date=start_date
            subset_thetao = DS[['thetao']].sel(time = slice(start_date, end_date))
            target_depth = 0 
            subset_depth = subset_thetao.thetao.isel(depth=target_depth)
            thetao_depth0 = subset_depth.data

But I'm having trouble adding up the arrays for each round of the loop.
I first tried things with np.sum but either it's not made for what I want to do, or I'm doing it wrong, especially when it comes to storing the array with the sum in a variable.
I've added empty_array = np.array([]) before my for loop but I don't know what to do next in the loop.
This is the first time I've handled arrays with python, so maybe I'm doing it wrong.
In the end, what I'd like to do is average the values of my different arrays over a month.
A simplified example with 3 days of a month :
array1([1,4,3,9]
       [7,5,2,3])

array2([3,8,6,1]
       [6,4,7,2])

array3([3,2,6,1]
       [1,4,5,2])

To get :
array([(1+3+3)/3,(4+8+2)/3,...etc]
       [...etc])

array([2.3,4.6,5,3.6]
       [4.6,4.3,4.6,2.3])


There's a way to programmatically download a subset from Copernicus. That should cut down on your preprocessing by selecting only thetao from your required date range

Similar problem with solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925902/sum-lists-value-with-corresponding-index-value-in-python

@Blend3rman Yes, I started with that, but the files are too big (1.6 GB for one day) if I want to run my script over the months of several years in one go. What's more, I have to hijack the code to download one file per day, otherwise it downloads a single file for the whole month and I want daily data. Finally, I'd like to adapt the start of my script so that it automatically runs on the right number of days in each month of each year. Another idea would have been to download the data only for a month, work on it and then delete it, but I'm not sure that's a better idea.

@qba-dev It adds up the dimensions of the same array when I want to add up the dimensions of different arrays, but thanks. Maybe it applies to me too, but I'm having trouble understanding the example given in the link and transposing it to my code.

@Camille Read the docs more thoroughly. You can download a specific variable for a specific depth range for a specific date range for a specific geographical area, from a specific dataset. I don't see how more granular you can get than this.


I've added empty_array = np.array([]) before my for loop but I don't know what to do next in the loop.

Almost right. You need to instantiate an array of the same shape as the arrays you will sum. With Numpy, you can only sum arrays of the same shape. You can inspect shape using arr.shape.
The array should initially be filled with zeros. This way, you end up with the sum after adding all your other arrays.
import numpy as np

# Create a zero-filled array with the same shape as the arrays you need to sum
sum_arr = np.zeros_like(thetao_depth0)

# alternative: sum_arr = np.zeros(thetao_depth0.shape)

for d in day:
    # ...
    # get the array subset_depth.data for the current day
    # ...

    # add the data of this day to the sum
    sum_arr += subset_depth.data


Your snippet
for y in year:
    for m in month:
        for d in day:
            start_date="%s"%y+"-%s"%m+"-%s"%d
            end_date=start_date
            subset_thetao = DS[['thetao']].sel(time = slice(start_date, end_date))
            target_depth = 0 
            subset_depth = subset_thetao.thetao.isel(depth=target_depth)
            thetao_depth0 = subset_depth.data

does not retain thetao_depth0 for subsequent days. Change the last line in the loop to
   thetao_depth0 = thetao_depth0 + subset_depth.data

However, you'll need to initialize thetao_depth0 to a zero-filled array of the same shape as subset_depth.data. From the snippets you've posted it looks like a multi-dimensional array, so you'll have to be careful with that.

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but using the answers above, I've done this which seems to work :
day = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']
month = ['01']
year = ['2014']

DS = copernicusmarine.open_dataset(dataset_id="cmems_mod_glo_phy_my_0.083deg_P1D-m")

sum_arr = np.zeros((2041,4320))

for y in year:
    for m in month:
        for d in day:
            start_date="%s"%y+"-%s"%m+"-%s"%d
            end_date=start_date
            subset_thetao = DS[['thetao']].sel(time = slice(start_date, end_date))
            target_depth = 0         #surface
            subset_depth = subset_thetao.thetao.isel(depth=target_depth)
            #print(subset_depth.data)
            for val in subset_depth :
                #print(val)
                sum_arr += val

mean = sum_arr/31

